# MySQL - SQL to skip intervals e.g. records every 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals

What I need.  An SQL statement that will look up a record, the newest, then look up the next record which is 5 minutes behind the timestamp of that record and repeat until limit is reached.  Timestamps are unix time.  So get newest record then subtract 5 minutes, get that record and repeat.  The 5 minutes is an example.  It well actually be a variable from second to hours.
I can easily program something in Perl, Ruby or Bash to do a loop with a select inside that works, but was hoping for a pure SQL way that might be faster.   Any help is appreciated.

**Added more info below.**

Below shows a very small clip of the records in the DB Table.  Basically data is inserted 20 seconds apart.  I want to be able to select a record at different intervals based on a variable passed through a CGI script, along with how many records I want total returned.

```
> select * from Sensor1 order by ts desc limit 5;
+------------+-------------+----------+
| ts         | temperature | humidity |
+------------+-------------+----------+
| 1407612981 |       75.91 |     56.5 |
| 1407612961 |       75.92 |     56.4 |
| 1407612941 |       75.92 |     56.5 |
| 1407612921 |       75.91 |     56.4 |
| 1407612901 |       75.91 |     56.4 |
+------------+-------------+----------+
```

So an example would be, I want the newest record, then the one 5 minutes back, then the one 5 more minutes back to some other variable passed by CGI script.
The below would be sample output based on wanting records that are the closest to 5 minutes apart for 5 iterations.

```
+------------+-------------+----------+
| ts         | temperature | humidity |
+------------+-------------+----------+
| 1407612681 |       75.92 |     56.4 |
| 1407612381 |       75.92 |     56.4 |
| 1407612081 |       75.90 |     56.3 |
| 1407611781 |       75.91 |     56.4 |
| 1407611481 |       75.90 |     56.4 |
+------------+-------------+----------+
```

So I can accomplish the above with a simple bash script.  See below.

```
#!/bin/bash
increment=5     # How many records we want
interval=300    # The number of seconds between each returned result
tc1=1
while [ $tc1 -lt $increment ]
do
  time=$(($time-$interval))    # This line makes sure our next select query is 300 seconds behind
  record=`echo "select * from Sensor${sensor} where ts >= ${time} order by ts asc limit 1;" | mysql -u env -penv -h localhost dc_temp | sed 's/\t/|/g' | grep -v "ts|temperature|humidity"`
  echo "Debug: ${record}"
  time=`echo $record | cut -d'|' -f1`  # Get the time from output.
  tc1=$((tc1+1))   # Add 1 to our temporary count to end the while loop when we reach how many records they want
done
```

So the above script gives me the output I want and control.  But I fear the huge number of Selects would be a slow down.  I'm looking to pull 24 hours, 1 week, 1 month, 1 year of data at different intervals between each record.  Basically for 24 hours, pull every 5 minutes.  For 1 week pull maybe a couple records an hour etc.  The data is all going to RGraph to create a line graph of the history temperature and humidity.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! Your question is a bit unclear I fear and you would better edit your question with a bit of sample data and the desired result. What is this next record? Is it the oldest record in the interval? What if there's no such record? Do you want a NULL then, ... The good part is: it can be done :-) The bad one: I don't know how efficient it will be.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TimeTable(value INT,time DATETIME);
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
INSERT dbo.TimeTable(value, time) SELECT 1, DATEADD(MINUTE, -7, GETDATE());
INSERT dbo.TimeTable(value, time) SELECT 2, DATEADD(MINUTE, -6, GETDATE());
INSERT dbo.TimeTable(value, time) SELECT 3, DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE());
INSERT dbo.TimeTable(value, time) SELECT 4, DATEADD(MINUTE, -4, GETDATE());
INSERT dbo.TimeTable(value, time) SELECT 5, DATEADD(MINUTE, -3, GETDATE());
INSERT dbo.TimeTable(value, time) SELECT 6, DATEADD(MINUTE, -2, GETDATE());
INSERT dbo.TimeTable(value, time) SELECT 7, DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, GETDATE());
INSERT dbo.TimeTable(value, time) SELECT 8, GETDATE();

;WITH myTbl AS
(
SELECT 
time, value, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY (DATEDIFF(Mi,0, time)/5) ORDER BY time desc) RK
FROM TimeTable
)

SELECT * FROM myTbl
WHERE RK <= 1
ORDER BY time DESC

DROP TABLE TimeTable
```

This will return the most recent record in every interval of 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I however was unable to make the suggested code work in MySQL.  It looks more for Microsoft SQL from the little experience I have had with Microsoft SQL.  I've added more info to my description now that I have had time to pull some sample data.  I'd appreciate any other thoughts on it.  Thank you!